# XCode 4 UILabel hidden doesn't seem to work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm having some display trouble wherein I manipulate a UILabel, and even though I use

`myLabel.hidden=YES;
...manipulation code...
myLabel.hidden=NO;`

the label never 'hides' and the manipulation (CATransform3DMakeRotation) is shown (you can see the label flip).

In XCode, I set a breakpoint at the "myLabel.hidden=YES;" line, but as I step through the code, it doesn't hide.

I must be missing something to get the "hidden" method to implement, right?
Some kind of refresh or update to the label?
Thanks...

Here's the code. "SetStartPosition" is called from several places, not just "doubleTap".

```
-(void)doubleTap{
    //stop the timer
    [myMover invalidate]; //the timer simply moves the label position
    myMover = nil;
    msgLabel.hidden=YES;
    isMirrored=!isMirrored;
    [self setStartPosition]; //flips the label
    msgLabel.hidden=NO;
    //restart the timer
    [self runMover];
}

- (void)setStartPosition{
    if(isMirrored){
        startPosition=(msgLabel.frame.size.width/2) * -1;
        msgLabel.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); //M_PI rotates 180 degrees
    }else{
        startPosition=(screenHeight)+(msgLabel.frame.size.width/2);
        msgLabel.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(0.0, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); //0.0 rotate to normal
    }
    newX=startPosition;
    newY=screenWidth/2;
    newFrame = msgLabel.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = screenWidth;
    newFrame.origin.x =newX;
    newFrame.origin.y=newY;
    msgLabel.frame = newFrame;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that myLabel is not `nil` ?

Answer (score 4):

No drawing is done during method execution, it is all done at the next drawing cycle. If your code above is all executed in the same method then the final state of the label will be visible, since you hide and then re-show it before any drawing is done.

If you expand your question to include more context it will be easier to offer a solution.

It looks as if you are getting an animation you don't want because you are modifying an animatable property of a CALayer, giving you an implicit animation. Please see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Transactions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006096-SW7) for guidance on how to override the timing of implicit animations - see "temporarily disabling layer actions"

An alternative is that you are being animated unintentionally because the timer method had queued up a pending change, and your transform is being done at the same time, so it is done in the animation. You should remove any animations from the label before changing the transform.

Comment: Assuming since you can see the label flip that you're doing this with an animation, you want the `myLabel.hidden=NO` in an after-animation handler.

Comment: @jrturton That explains it. Basically, in the same method I do the following (pseudo code): `hide label, execute method to transform, show label` So what do I do? Is there a way to force a drawing cycle?

Comment: @smparkes - that's my guess too but I don't like to speculate too much in answers!

Comment: @smparkes It's pretty simple - I'm using a timer to move the label position. Even if I stop the timer, make my changes, then re-start the timer I get the same visual.

Comment: @wayneh put your actual code in the question. How are you doing the animation etc. though I have to wonder, why are you animating if you want it to be invisible?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7105/discussion-between-wayneh-and-jrturton)

Comment: @jrturton I'm not using animation methods - just the timer to modify the position of the label. So, I'm not sure why the "hidden" isn't working, but I can see the transform?